# run multiple steps in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

In my project, I have requirements to run multiple steps.

I followed this guideline  : [Jenkins Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#:%7E:text=Jenkins%20Pipeline%20allows%20you%20to,correctly%20the%20Pipeline%20will%20fail.)

Here are the code :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Hello World"'
                sh '''
                    echo "Multiline shell steps works too"
                    ls -lah
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have other alternative to handle the multiple steps in Jenkins pipeline ? I also thinking to use script inside steps I am not sure that's also good way to do

I am trying to understand what is the best practice to run multiple steps

Answer (score 1):

You need to better define what it is you intend to. Do. A starting [example is here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#pipeline-example) .

You need to understand the [meaning of stage and step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#pipeline-concepts).

> A stage block defines a conceptually distinct subset of tasks performed through the entire Pipeline (e.g. "Build", "Test" and "Deploy" stages)
>
> Step: A single task. Fundamentally, a step tells Jenkins what to do at a particular point in time (or "step" in the process).

You need to think of both stage and step as atomic units. Eg: Deploy is an atomic activity, but may consist of numerous steps, some of which might have multiple instructions/commands, copy artifact (to different targets, copy data, , launch app. etc.

This [Tutorial](https://github.com/ssbostan/jenkins-tutorial) may be useful, too.
Also, review [best practices](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/pipeline-best-practices/)